# GetAsync from unknown IPAddress cause application to crash

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

Appliction:

- A WPF Application using HttpClient to asynchronously get data from a Web API(eg.: "http://<**ServerIP**>/api/GetData")
- Getting data interval: 3s;

Sample Code:

```
    //initialize
    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.100");
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


    //get data method
    //......
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri); //called every 3 seconds
    //......
```

Three situation :

1. When the **ServerIP** is the right one providing Web API Service, the WPF Application works fine;
2. When the **ServerIP** is a known IP that do not provide the right Web API Service, which will cause exceptions in System.dll(SocketException -> WebException -> ObjectDisposedException -> HttpRequestException ->...Which should be normal), but still the WPF Application will not crash;
3. When the **ServerIP** does not exist, exception caused in **System.dll**(SocketException -> WebException -> ObjectDisposedException -> HttpRequestException ->...again, which should be normal), but after several minutes, it will cause a "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException" in **mscorlib.dll**, and then the WPF Application **crashes**.

Question:

- How to deal with the TaskCanceledException in situation 3 above, and prevent the application from crashing?

**Update1**:

- Actually, i forgot to catch the TaskCanceledException, which can be catch in the application code of course;

So, **problem solved**.

Comment: Can you show some code? Why not catching the exception? with try catch, or if you are "firing and forgetting" have a continuation on fault. In .NET when a task throws an exception and it's not caught the process will be terminated.

Comment: those exceptions are thrown in System.dll and mscorlib.dll, so no way to catch them.

Comment: So the exception is not propagated to your code?

Comment: Dean the awaited function never returns? That is a very odd behavior. Exceptions being thrown in System or mscorlib is normal, are you sure that you don't have any other task running that is causing this problems?

Comment: the repeating getdata thread is the only one, (SocketException -> WebException -> ObjectDisposedException -> HttpRequestException -> ...) indicates that the http connection is not created successfully and returns. I am curious that in **situation 2**, the application does not crash.